# Find middle number in array object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an array object:

```js
var checkin_status = [{
    "startdate":"2015-01-08",
    "totaldays":"4",  
    "roadmap":[
        { "gifttype": "stars", "quantity": 100, "day": 1},
        { "gifttype": "stars", "quantity": 500, "day": 3},
        { "gifttype": "stars", "quantity": 1000, "day": 10},
        { "gifttype": "stars", "quantity": 1200, "day": 20},
        { "gifttype": "stars", "quantity": 2200, "day": 30},
    ]
}];

var checkin_info = checkin_status[0].roadmap;
var total = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < checkin_info.length; ++i){
    total += checkin_info[i].day;
    alert(total);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

This code is tried so far, I need the object add the next index number, for example : day `1`+ day `3` = `4` , then next will be `3` + `10` = `13` and so on. Output I need is like `4,13,20,50` .

Any idea how to do this ?

Comment: i m not happy.:( what exactly do you want?

Comment: This seems like a homework assignment. Have you made any attempt to achieve this yourself? Also shouldn't the output be `4, 13, 30, 50`?

Comment: @NaeemShaikh i need the array value sum the next array value. you can see day array is `1,3,10,20,30` , I need the sum will be `1+3=4` , `3+10=13`, `10+20=30` , `20+30=50` , so the output i need is `4,14,30,50`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan `4, 13, 30, 50` is because the array value sum the next array value

Answer (score 1):

Here is for loop answer:

```js
var checkin_status = [{
  "startdate": "2015-01-08",
  "totaldays": "4",
  "roadmap": [{
    "gifttype": "stars",
    "quantity": 100,
    "day": 1
  }, {
    "gifttype": "stars",
    "quantity": 500,
    "day": 3
  }, {
    "gifttype": "stars",
    "quantity": 1000,
    "day": 10
  }, {
    "gifttype": "stars",
    "quantity": 1200,
    "day": 20
  }, {
    "gifttype": "stars",
    "quantity": 2200,
    "day": 30
  }, ]
}];

var checkin_info = checkin_status[0].roadmap;
var output = [];
for (var i = 1; i < checkin_info.length; ++i) {
  output.push(checkin_info[i - 1].day + checkin_info[i].day);
}
console.log(output);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Here is jquery each answer:

```js
var checkin_status = [{
  "startdate": "2015-01-08",
  "totaldays": "4",
  "roadmap": [{
    "gifttype": "stars",
    "quantity": 100,
    "day": 1
  }, {
    "gifttype": "stars",
    "quantity": 500,
    "day": 3
  }, {
    "gifttype": "stars",
    "quantity": 1000,
    "day": 10
  }, {
    "gifttype": "stars",
    "quantity": 1200,
    "day": 20
  }, {
    "gifttype": "stars",
    "quantity": 2200,
    "day": 30
  }, ]
}];
var checkin_info = checkin_status[0].roadmap;
var output = [];
$.each(checkin_status[0].roadmap, function(index, obj) {
  if (index === 0)
    return;
  output.push(checkin_info[index - 1].day + obj.day);
});
console.log(output);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: if I not use `for` use `$.each` how to declare the `[i-1]`  ?

Comment: `$.each(checkin_info, function(i,obj) {` so is `obj[i-1].day + obj.day` ?

Comment: obj[i-1] is not a valid statement. use checkin_info[i -1] instead

Comment: first index is zero. hence checkin_info[-1] is undefined. You need to continue on that condition.

Comment: any other way for `checkin_info[index - 1].day` ? because if I `if (index === 0) return;` will affect some other code. if i take away `Cannot read property 'day' of undefined`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68798/discussion-between-praveen-prasannan-and-im-happy).

Answer (score 0):

Try this too:

```
array  = checkin_status[0].roadmap.map(function(d){return d.day})
a=0; b=[];
array.forEach(function(d){
    if(a != 0){
         b.push(a+d)};
         a = d
    }
)
console.log(b)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    var checkin_status = [{
      "startdate": "2015-01-08",
      "totaldays": "4",
      "roadmap": [{
        "gifttype": "stars",
        "quantity": 100,
        "day": 1
      }, {
        "gifttype": "stars",
        "quantity": 500,
        "day": 3
      }, {
        "gifttype": "stars",
        "quantity": 1000,
        "day": 10
      }, {
        "gifttype": "stars",
        "quantity": 1200,
        "day": 20
      }, {
        "gifttype": "stars",
        "quantity": 2200,
        "day": 30
      }, ]
    }];

    var checkin_info = checkin_status[0].roadmap;
    var total = 0;
    for (var i = 1; i < checkin_info.length; ++i){
        total = checkin_info[i-1].day + checkin_info[i].day;
         if (typeof total !== 'undefined'){
           console.log(total);
         }
    }
```